# Xamarin.Forms String format not displaying binding information

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to display Product prices in a string format in Xamarin Forms:

```
Text="{Binding Price,  StringFormat=' Price is  {0:$}'}"
```

**Output:**

Price is $

what I am doing wrong and why the binded price is not displaying?

Comment: Try using the currency format `{0:c}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the Currency Format instead.

```
<Label Text="{Binding Price StringFormat='Price is = {0:C}'}" />
```